# Concatenate dataframe value to each list element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe that contains two columns. The first one contains spare parts and the second one contains "list" of models, where it fits. It is not a list per se, the format is a string delimited by semicolumn.

| Spare part | Models |
| --- | --- |
| sparepart1 | model1;model3;model4 |
| sparepart2 | model1;model2;model3 |

I need to revert the logic, so that I can see which parts each model contains:

| Model | sparepart |
| --- | --- |
| model1 | sparepart1;sparepart2 |
| model2 | sparepart2 |
| model3 | sparepart1;sparepart2 |
| model4 | sparepart1 |

I tried to create every model-spare part combination by using concatenate, but did not succeed.

Any hints how to proceed?

Thanks

Stepan

Comment: You say lists, you show concatenated-by-`';'` strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) `Models` column, and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the, list, and then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `Models` and [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by `str.join`.

```
>>> ( df.assign(Models=df.Models.str.split(';'))
        .explode('Models')
        .groupby('Models', as_index=False).agg(';'.join))

   Models             Spare part
0  model1  sparepart1;sparepart2
1  model2             sparepart2
2  model3  sparepart1;sparepart2
3  model4             sparepart1
```

Comment: Hello Sayandip,

thanks for your reply. I tested your approach and got something different:

| model    | spare_part      |
| --------    | --------------       |
| model 1  | spare_part;model|
| model 2  | spare_part;model|


The explode part worked just fine, but it seems I am not able to get the list of spare parts using this approach. The values in the spare_part columns contain column headers instead of spare part codes.

Any guess how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Stepan